# How did 'pummel' evolve from the meaning of apple?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation behind [ODO's definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pummel)  that helps to remember its meaning?

> **to pummel** = [with object]
>   1. Strike repeatedly with the fists
>   1.1. [North American, informal] Criticize severely:
>
> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pommel&allowed_in_frame=0): mid-13c., "ornamental knob;" c.1300, "knob at the end of a sword hilt," from Old French pomel (12c., Modern French pommeau), "rounded knob," diminutive of pom "hilt of a sword," from Late Latin pomellum, diminutive of Latin **pomum** "apple" (see Pomona), the connecting notion being "roundness." Sense of "front peak of a saddle" first recorded mid-15c. In Middle English poetry it also sometimes meant a woman's breast. The gymnast's pommel horse is attested from 1908.

I recognise 'une pomme' from French but how does 'roundness' induce the current meaning?

Comment: Hooray, your link doesn't point to *leverage*! :) I quite like your question too. But I'd say *apple* refers to the shape of a closed fist.

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pomo/ look at def. 5

Comment: I would imagine that the counterbalace ball at the end of a Roman sword was roughly  the size and shape of a Roman dessert apple. Apples, particularly cooking apples, have become larger in more recent times but without modern selective breeding and cultivation techniques they tend to revert to around 50 to 75 mm in diameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visually quite obvious.

Pummel someone with the (apple shaped) ornamental knob at the end of your sword.

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Albion_Talhoffer_Medieval_Sword_(pommel).jpg]

> Albion Talhoffer Medieval Sword (pommel)

<sub>source: [WikiMedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Albion_Talhoffer_Medieval_Sword_(pommel).jpg)</sub>

A standard movement in infighting

[image]
<sub>(source: [aemma.org](http://www.aemma.org/onlineResources/liberi/wildRose/section5_files/179.jpg))</sub>

> Because my sword has received a hit and because of 
>   my grab, I'll hit your face with my pommel.

<sub>source: [The Sign of the Sword](http://www.aemma.org/onlineResources/liberi/wildRose/section5.html)</sub>

---

Answer (score 0):

The Etymonline entry that you cite is for *pommel*, the noun meaning "the ball at the end of a sword". *Pummel*, the verb, appears to mean *to strike with, or as with, a pommel*.

Johnson's *A dictionary of the English Language* of 1768 has an entry for *pummel*, but only as a variant of *pommel* (as a noun). It defines *pommel* both as a noun, and as the verb we now know as *pummel*:

> To POMMEL: To beat black and blue; to bruise; to punch.

([Entry](http://books.google.com/books?id=bXsCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT7#v=onepage&q=pommel&f=false))

And Johnson and Walker's *Dictionary of the English Language*, published in 1828, has the following:

> To POMMEL: **To beat with anything thick or bulky**; to bruise; to punch.

([Entry](http://books.google.com/books?id=z3kKAAAAIAAJ&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q=pommel&f=false); emphasis added)